# Modify msg file

Tags: ros, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI ,
I try to modify an msg file ( add new field) : this my code

```
float64[3] hand_direction
float64[3] hand_normal
float64[3] hand_translation /: this is the new field 
float64[3] hand_palm_pos
float64 hand_pitch
float64 hand_roll
float64 hand_yaw
```

When i type   $ rosmsg show leapros.msg
i get the old content

```
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
geometry_msgs/Vector3 direction
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
geometry_msgs/Vector3 normal
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
geometry_msgs/Point palmpos
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
geometry_msgs/Vector3 ypr
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
```

why i can't modify the msg file content ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188446/modify-msg-file/) by [ameni mighri](https://answers.ros.org/users/19760/ameni-mighri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-07-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-31**:
Sorry my crystal ball is broken, we need more information. Please write HOW you tried to modify the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All the code to support **messages is auto-generated**, so for your changes on the *.msg* file to be effective the easiest way is to **re-build your package**.

If you are using a catking workspace try to rebuild it:

```
$ cd your_catking_ws
$ catkin_make
```

This will re-generate your messages using the new message specification.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0